# AndEndine - PhysicsBox2D - gravity and collision with different sprite/bodytype

Tags: java, android, box2d, andengine

I am a beginner AndEngine user. I want to try the PhysicsBox2D extension but I
do not know how to handle it.

I want that the character stops moving down if he collides with the blue boxes. But the blue 
boxes should move down too if the box below disappear (detach).

My problem is: 
- when I set the character and box bodyType to dynamic the character just falls without colliding with box. 
- The other way is: character dynamic and box static -> the box will not fall.

What I want: character should collide with box and stop its movement and when boxes below disappear the upper boxes should move with gravity.

Could someone give me an example how to code it?

image: http://image-upload.de/image/ojqr0R/c83b21bfdc.jpg

Comment: if the character comes to a upper box which is not having base(i.e  bottom box) then that upper box has to fall  down?

Comment: No they should not fall if the character collides with it. But if I would remove the bottom box all upper boxes and the character body should fall down.